# Is it possible to see which lines were executed after a command-line app was run?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, mingw, interpreter

I am using MinGW (GCC) as a C++ compiler within my application. I have set it to redirect the output of its command line process to my app. Now, suppose I have the following simple C++ code:

```
int n = 5;
if (n == 6) cout << "YES";
else cout << "NO";
```

Is there a way to tell what line(s) of code were actually hit during execution of the application? Is there a command I can send to MinGW (GCC) process which, for the given example, would output 1 and 3, as those were the lines hit. And also, in case of a line inside a "for" loop, to tell how many times that statement was actually hit?

And, if not possible, what would be the best approach to having this information? Developing my own compiler or...? Thanks in advance

EDIT: Can someone provide a snippet of commands (in Windows) to be used in order to create a coverage-enabled GCC exe file?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "code coverage".

Comment: Thanks, can you be a little bit more specific? A little little clue would suffice I guess... thanks!

Comment: There are many, many tools out there for it. Google 'c++ code coverage'.

Comment: Yes, I guess I found something built along with GCC: gcov and gprof: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html. Thanks, that was the term I never knew I was actually looking for...

Comment: @aruisdante It's a very, very specific GCC feature though (since the question is tagged for this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is there a way to tell what line(s) of code were actually hit during execution of the application?"*

Yes. It's an intrinsic GCC feature. You'll need to compile and link your code with the [`--coverage`, `-lgcov` or `-fprofile-arcs`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) options set.

The [`gcov` tool](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) can be used to consolidate and interpret the actual informations gathered during program runs, that were instrumented with `--coverage`.

A very good tool to produce browsable consolidated and fairly visualized covearage information from `gcov` outputs is [**lcov**](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php).

Comment: Thanks, I use --coverage as a command-line argument, but no gcda file is produced. Does this work with g++.exe, as this is what I use to compile the app?

Comment: @ValentinRadu Usually it works with `g++`, did you provide the mentioned linker options also, when you create the final executable?

Comment: Yes, his is how my command line looks: g++ -g --coverage -o temp.exe temp.cpp

Comment: @ValentinRadu Add `-lgcov` as mentioned (could be a weak linking problem)

Comment: @ValentinRadu Well, all I can tell you is, it works well with various setups for me. Though I didn't use a MinGW environment so far. Also note, the outputs during program execution are written along the object files, that were used when linking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using mingw you should be able to use gcov: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html